# Handle 'Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.' error in Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, safari, cors

I am working on an Angular app.

Using the APIs I get this error:

```
'Origin http://localhost:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'
```

I am able to use browser extensions to avoid this in Chrome and Firefox.

However, in Safari it does not have such extensions.

I also set the 'Disable local file restrictions' on the Safari browser too.

**QUESTION**

How do I resolve this error in Safari?

Comment: You can avoid CORS problems by using a local server.. I like 'live-server' from npm, it refreshes the server every time you make a change to a file

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to communicate from http (on your local app) to https and Safari blocks it.
You can run your app locally also on http protocol.